# How to retrieve forums and messages in a group with the Facebook API?

Tags: .net, facebook

I started to play with .net Facebook API on a desktop app. I would like to do a simple reader of secret group forums. Does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve it?
I found a way to post comments, but retrieving comments needs xid ad filter and I'm not even sure if it's the right API. Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: If you have discovered something about, plz post it here, I am also interested

Answer (score 0):

Using the Graph API, its possible to get a list of the groups a user is a member of, and GET and POST content to that group via the API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the answer. Have no time to test it now, but it looks promising.